# Selecting a Diff report from one table MySQL

Tags: mysql, self-join

I've been trying to write a MySQL query to handle a difference report for **Approved = 'yes'** vs. **Approved = 'no'** rows in a single table. -- I've tried a few methods (including self-join and creating/querying temp tables) and no matter what I try I end up with the wrong data set output.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT a.*
    FROM myTable a
    JOIN myTable b
    ON a.apples = b.apples
    AND a.bananas = b.bananas
    AND a.oranges = b.oranges
    WHERE (
        a.Approved = 'no'
        AND b.Approved = 'yes'
    ) AND ( 
        a.diffVal1 <> b.diffVal1
        OR a.diffVal2 <> b.diffVal2
        OR a.diffVal3 <> b.diffVal3
    )
```

In this case, I'm trying to compare rows that have the same apples, bananas, and oranges... And, if any of the diffVal's between the compared rows aren't the same, I want to include that row in the set being output.  I'm not sure why this isn't working, but every time I run this, it includes all 'no' entries regardless of whether or not there's a 'yes' entry with the same apples, bananas, and oranges that has differences in the diffVals. ( almost like it's ignoring the diffVal section all together )

I'm sure it's something stupid I'm overlooking, but if any of you have any suggestions, I would greatly appreciate them.

Populated Table

---

```
    id  apples  bananas  oranges  diffVal1  diffVal2  diffVal3  Approved
    1   red     yellow   orange   a         b           c       yes
    2   red     yellow   orange   a         b           c       yes
    3   red     green    orange   a         b           c       yes
    4   red     yellow   orange   a         b           c       no
    5   red     yellow   orange   a         H           c       no
    6   green   yellow   orange   a         H           c       no
    7   red     yellow   orange   a         b           d       yes
    8   red     yellow   orange   a         b           e       yes
    9   red     yellow   orange   a         b           c       yes
    10  red     yellow   orange   a         b           c       yes
    11  red     yellow   orange   a         b           c       yes
    12  red     yellow   orange   a         b           c       yes
    13  red     yellow   orange   a         b           c       no
    14  red     yellow   orange   a         b           c       no
    15  red     yellow   orange   a         b           c       no
    16  red     yellow   orange   d         d           d       no
```

Actual Results from running the above stated query

---

```
    5   red yellow  orange  a   H   c   no
    16  red yellow  orange  d   d   d   no
    4   red yellow  orange  a   b   c   no
    13  red yellow  orange  a   b   c   no
    14  red yellow  orange  a   b   c   no
    15  red yellow  orange  a   b   c   no
```

As you can see, it's included rows in the output where red yellow orange has a b c for diffVals, despite the fact that there are 'yes' entries with red yellow orange that have a b c for diffVals.

Expected Results

---

```
    5   red yellow  orange  a   H   c   no
    16  red yellow  orange  d   d   d   no
```

---

-- My apologies for the formatting. I tried to add screenshots but since I'm new, stack overflow won't let me add images.

Comment: show your table structure and sample input and output

Comment: What is the exact desired output that you're expecting to get?

Comment: The first two rows should have been the only rows output (based on what I'm trying for)  The last 4 rows are all rows with the same values as an existing 'yes' row, so they shouldn't be output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM table1 t
 WHERE approved = 'no'
   AND EXISTS
(
  SELECT *
    FROM table1
   WHERE approved = 'yes'
     AND apples   = t.apples
     AND bananas  = t.bananas
     AND oranges  = t.oranges
)
   AND NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT *
    FROM table1
   WHERE approved = 'yes'
     AND apples   = t.apples
     AND bananas  = t.bananas
     AND oranges  = t.oranges
     AND diffval1 = t.diffval1 
     AND diffval2 = t.diffval2 
     AND diffval3 = t.diffval3
);
```

Output:

```
| ID | APPLES | BANANAS | ORANGES | DIFFVAL1 | DIFFVAL2 | DIFFVAL3 | APPROVED |
|----|--------|---------|---------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
|  5 |    red |  yellow |  orange |        a |        H |        c |       no |
| 16 |    red |  yellow |  orange |        d |        d |        d |       no |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/124ba/12)** demo

Comment: Awesome! Thank you, That is exactly what I needed. I'm still not really sure why my query didn't produce the same results, (maybe due to table locking/comparing different rows at different times?) Anyway. Thanks man I owe you a beer.